# Java regex negative lookahead not working properly

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a struggle creating a regex that verifies if a string does not end in a sequence of X characters (the same one).

For example: x=5

```
1xxxxx - should fail
1xxx - should pass
```

My regex so far : `1(?!\\w\1{4})` does not work. Returns false in both cases.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `1(\d)(?!.*\1{3}).*` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cczl1P/1

Comment: Very good answear! But I don't understand why when trying to make the regex more complex using capturing groups it doesn't work anymore. What I am trying to do is: check that 1 is followed by exactly X characters and that those X characters are not the same.

Comment: It's not a capturing group, it looks like one but it's a negative look ahead. Your question is not very specific. If you can include the strings you want to match and those which you don't want to match, you will get a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/cczl1P/4

Comment: I've created https://www.regex101.com/r/cczl1P/10   I'm trying to match the "google" codes that have exactly 18 non identical chars after GOOGLE-DE-. What am I missing there? First 3 examples should pass, the rest not.

Comment: Check this: https://www.regex101.com/r/cczl1P/12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133151/discussion-between-user3159152-and-mygz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add end of string anchor:

```
1(?!.*(.)\1{4,}$).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one, but if the condition in your question is correct, "string does not end in a sequence of X characters", this should do it:

```
(?:(.)(?:(?:(?!\1).){1,4})|^(.)\2{0,3})$
```

It's basically two possible alterations inside a non-capturing group `(?:` - `)`.

The last part - `^(.)\2{0,3}` - simply tests if its a complete string consisting of only one character, less than five long.

The first part - `(.)(?:(?:(?!\1).){1,4})` - checks for a change of character by capturing one, and by a negative look-ahead making sure it doesn't match the next one, which is matched by the `.` and tested for a repetition of less than four times

The both alterations is tested for end of string `$` outside the group.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lAYwE2/2).